# PostgreSQL Gap lock by SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, locking

There is a query with a [Gap Lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks) used at MySQL/InnoDB:

```
SELECT id, time, count
FROM table_a
WHERE time
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
    AND NOW()
FOR UPDATE
```

It locks the `time` range and returns a recent record if present (during last 24 hrs).
If not - the session still owns a lock over the duration of last 24 hours to safely insert a new record.

Is is possible to make the same gap lock for entire 24 hours duration (even if there are no records) in PostgreSQL?

Comment: No, you can't lock rows, that aren't there. But I don't see how your table stores a "range" to begin with, when it only has a single column called `time` (which probably is a `timestamp` rather than `time`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do that in PostgreSQL is to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level for all transactions.

Then you don't need the `FOR UPDATE` at all. PostgreSQL won't prevent rows from being inserted in the gap, but if two transactions both read and write values in the same gap simultaneously, one of them will get a serialization error and have to redo the transaction (on the second try, it will find the gap not empty).

The concept at work here is serializability: it is acceptable if someone else inserts into the gap *without reading* (that transaction is *logically after* the one with your `SELECT`). But if two transactions both find the gap empty and then insert something, that would create an anomaly that is prevented by `SERIALIZABLE`.

Comment: Technically, when you will switch to the SERIALIZABLE level, you get a lot of different problems, like serialization errors (40001). And next you will think about: retrying policy, circuit breaker, while true loops and so on. Think about advisory locking instead.